# reporting Wednesday to wednesday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying run a report based on a Wednesday to Wednesday reporting week.
I have found lots of examples that say the get correct date, such as:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -5, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

The problem is that these seem to only work for the **current** week. The example above gives 15/11/17 which is correct for today (24/11/2017) but incorrect on Sunday (26/11/2017) when it would get the 22/11/2017.

if I look at the report between **22-28/11/2017**(Wed-Tue) I should  see a report from **15-22/11/2017**

Between the **29/11 & 5/12/2017** the report should be from **22-29/11/2017**

any help is appreciated!

Comment: the result needs to give the last complete Wednesday to Wednesday date. no future dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN [wensday]>reportDate THEN DATEADD(WEEK,-2,[wensday]) ELSE DATEADD(WEEK,-1,[wensday]) END [from date],
  CASE WHEN [wensday]>reportDate THEN DATEADD(WEEK,-1,[wensday]) ELSE [wensday] END [to date]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      reportDate,
      -- monday of this week
      --DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,reportDate)/7*7,0) [monday],
      -- wensday of this week
      DATEADD(DAY,2,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,reportDate)/7*7,0)) [wensday]
    FROM
      (
        SELECT CAST('20171115' AS date) reportDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST('20171121' AS date) reportDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST('20171122' AS date) reportDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST('20171123' AS date) reportDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST('20171124' AS date) reportDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST('20171129' AS date) reportDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST('20171205' AS date) reportDate
      ) test
  ) q
```

The inline algorithm

```
DECLARE @reportDate date=GETDATE()

DECLARE @Wensday date=DATEADD(DAY,2,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@reportDate)/7*7,0))
DECLARE @FromDate date=CASE WHEN @Wensday>@reportDate THEN DATEADD(WEEK,-2,@Wensday) ELSE DATEADD(WEEK,-1,@Wensday) END
DECLARE @ToDate date=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@FromDate)

SELECT @reportDate,@Wensday,@FromDate,@ToDate
```

Comment: thanks, This also to work will give a couple of tests let you know!

Comment: makes lots of sense and works well. thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATEFIRST to assign days 1-7 to Wed - Tue

Whatever date you put in here, it will return the first prior Wednesday

The following Tuesday is just 6 days after that.

```
-- Wednesday will be 1 when we use datepart dw
SET DATEFIRST 3;

DECLARE @ReportDate DATE
SET @ReportDate = '2017-11-26'


SELECT 
DATEADD(    d,
            -(DATEPART(dw,@ReportDate)-1),
            @ReportDate
        )
```

Comment: thanks, This looks good so far i will test it a little bit and let you know1

Comment: How did this work out for you? if it helped please tick it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @fDt as date,@fDtR as date
set @fDt = '11/15/2017'
SET DATEFIRST 3
SELECT @fDtR = DATEADD(d,-6-(DATEPART(dw,@fDt)),@fDt)
print @fDtR
```

Comment: Thanks,
but this looks like it picks the next Wednesdays date not

Comment: still gives the same result. when the @fDt is 22-28/11/2017 the output needs to be **15th**.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select * from youtablename where yourdatefield <= 
 dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7 * 7 + 2,0)) and yourdatefield > 
 dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7 * 7 + 2,-7))
```

From this you will get last wednesday

```
select 
 dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7 * 7 + 2,0))
```

and from this you will get last to last wednesday

```
select dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7 * 7 + 2,-7))
```

so that you can find Wednesday to Wednesday data.

Comment: Thanks, this has the same problem I currently have.
It doesn't  give a complete week. if you change your get date() to '11/21/2017'
it gives :
Nov 15 2017 12:00AM-
Nov 22 2017 12:00AM


which is an incomplete week. the correct results would be
Nov 8 2017 12:00AM-
Nov 15 2017 12:00AM

Comment: please provide proper example what you want actully

Comment: return the last Wednesday to Wednesday dates. The result can't be in the future. Example. 22nd Nov to 28th Nov should return 15th -22nd Nov thanks.